# viewcontroller with a uinvaigationcontroller when pop up does not show the navbar

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I'm using storyboards with this. On the storyboard I have a "mainpage" uiviewcontroller that has a button which when tap will call another uiviewcontroller (choosewinner) to pop up. But this choosewinner vc has a uinavigation controller attached to it, reason why is so that it can go back and forth easily. Now I can call the uiview as a modal pop up but it doesn't show it's uinavigation.

This is the method called when the button is tapped. Thoughts?

```
- (void)updateWinner{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    MatchWinnerViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WinnerViewController"];

    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
    vc.view.superview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    vc.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 600);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you have the `MatchWinnerViewController` with `UINavigationController` attached to it in the storyboard, if you want to present it modally with the `UINavigationController`, you need to supply the navigation controller as the parameter to the method `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.

The reason is that for modal presentation, it takes the root view controller, and a navigation controller is also a view controller.